# Transferring binary data using sockets in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to create a Client-Server model of file transferring in Java in which the client will read a file and send the data to the server and the server will receive the data and write it to a file. I had already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814154/binary-file-transfer-over-socket-using-tcp) post, but it deals with C.

I wrote a simple algorithm which would just send the file as soon it connects to the server.
This is the code for the client:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
            System.out.println("Connected to " + s.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            File file = new File(args[2]);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int no_of_bytes = 0;
            while ((no_of_bytes = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                dout.write(buffer, 0, no_of_bytes);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for the server:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected to " + s.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            File new_file = new File("/home/Puspam/Videos/received.png");
            new_file.createNewFile();
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new_file));
            int a;
            while ((a = din.read()) != -1) {
                bw.write((char) a);
            }
            din.close();
            bw.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

After running the two programs with an image file for the experiment, I could find that the file has not been transferred properly. When I try to open the received file, the image viewer software in my PC shows an error that it is not a valid image file. Also, I could see that the received file is a bit larger than the original one.
What mistake am I doing here?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is using a `Writer`. You can use exactly the same code at both ends, after you've got the correct input and output streams. Use the first piece of code you posted here, with a `FileOutpitStream`, and a `BufferedOutputStream` around it if you like. NB 1. You don't need to call `createNewFile()`. 2. Use a bigger buffer. 3. You need to close the output, not just flush it.

Comment: NB 4. You don't need the `DataInput/OutputStreams` here.

Comment: I haven't fully got you. I need to read the file in the client code, so how can I use `FileOutputStream`?

Comment: I'm referring to the server code with the `Writer`. There's no reason for it to be any different  from the client code other than the actual streams.

Answer (score -1):

I've had this kinda thing before. Try to use the same type of Input/Output Stream on both ends. Like, BufferedReader to BufferedWriter, etc. You're using a FileInputStream in conjunction with a BufferedWriter. Also, you may need to flush the BufferedWriter in every iteration of your *for* loop.

Comment: 1. He is sending binary data. `Reader` and `Writer` are therefore completely out of the question. 2. Flushing inside a loop accomplishes exactly nothing except losi all the benefits of buffering.